# overflowed grid won't shrink when resize viewport

Tags: css, chakra-ui

I have a grid component that will overflow. but the problem is it prevent its container from resize to fit viewport in mobile mode.
here's the stripped down grid component that I use.
UI lib I use is Chakra UI

```
    <Container maxW={"container.lg"} bgColor={"white"} p={5}>
      <Grid
        minW={0}
        overflowX={"scroll"}
        templateColumns={`repeat(12, 140px)`}
        templateRows={"40px auto"}
        bg={"white"}
      >
        {[
          "JAN",
          "FEB",
          "MAR",
          "APR",
          "MAY",
          "JUN",
          "JUL",
          "AUG",
          "SEP",
          "OCT",
          "NOV",
          "DEC",
        ].map((item, k) => (
          <GridItem key={k} bg={"#EBEBEB"} border={"1px solid #EBEBEB"}>
            <Center h="full">{item}</Center>
          </GridItem>
        ))}

        {Array(12)
          .fill("")
          .map((_, k) => (
            <GridItem
              key={k}
              id={k}
              borderLeft={"1px solid #B9B9B9"}
              borderRight={"1px solid #B9B9B9"}
              height={"145px"}
            ></GridItem>
          ))}
      </Grid>
    </Container>
```

I did add minWidth to component, wrap grid in another component, change previous container to flex, etc.
but it do work with Chakra UI modal, but I tried to replicate it but won't work, I still don't know why it work there but not here.